# What is the chance that there are not 4 or more consecutive white balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

There are 7 white balls in a row and a fair die (a cube with numbers 1, 2,..., 6 in its six faces). We roll the die 7 times and paint the ith balls into black if we get either 5 or 6 in the ith roll.

(a) What is the expected number of black balls?

(b) What is the chance that there exist 6 or more consecutive black balls?

(c) What is the chance that there are not 4 or more consecutive white balls?

Our study group has answered (a) and (b) and are confident we got those correct. We are just having trouble with the last one (c).

(a) We reasoned that the over all experiment can be modeled by a Binomial(7,$\frac{1}{3}$) where $\frac{1}{3}$ is the probability of painting a ball black (probability of rolling a 5 or 6). Therefore the expected value is just $7 \times \frac{1}{3} \approx 2.3$.

(b) There are only 2 ways to get exactly 6 consecutive black balls so $2 \times (\frac{1}{3})^6$ and one way to get 7 consecutive black balls $(\frac{1}{3})^7$. Therefore P(6 or more consecutive black balls) $= 2 \times (\frac{2}{3})(\frac{1}{3})^6 + (\frac{1}{3})^7$.

(c) So we decided to attempt to calculate it as 1 - P(4 or more consecutive white balls). We believe that we could possibly brute force this by literally finding the probability of every combination of 4 or more consecutive white balls. The problem is that we are studying this question to help us prep for a qualification exam and believe that there should be a non-brute force way to solve it for it to be a valid exam question.

Comment: I assume that you mean "at least $4$ consecutive whites", so $W^7$ would be a fail for $c$, but you should clarify.  Assuming I have it right, I'd do it recursively.  Note that a sequence without $4$ consecutive whites must begin with one of $B,WB, W^2B, W^3B$.

Comment: Should say:  My proposal, while quite easy, isn't exactly easy with pen and paper.  Takes just a few seconds with Excel or any sort of software, and not much more with a standard calculator, but I'd want some mechanical assistance.

Comment: To obtain exactly six consecutive black balls, you must either obtain a white ball then six consecutive black balls, with probability $$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^6,$$ or obtain six consecutive black balls and then a white ball, with the same probability.

Comment: Correct! I just made a mistake in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a recursive method:

Let $P(n)$ denote the answer for a string of length $n$ . We remark that $$n≤3\implies P(n)=1 \quad \&\quad P(4)=1-\left(\frac 23\right)^4$$

For $n>4$ we remark that if a sequence is good then it must begin with exactly one of $B,WB,W^2B,W^3B$ and of course it must then be followed by a good sequence of shorter length.  It follows that $$P(n)=\frac 13\times P(n-1)+\frac 23\times \frac 13\times P(n-2)+\left( \frac 23\right)^2\times \frac 13\times P(n-3)+\left( \frac 23\right)^3\times \frac 13\times P(n-4)$$

This is very easy to implement mechanically, maybe a bit slow to do with pencil and paper.

We get $$P(5)=0.736625514,\quad P(6)=0.670781893,\quad\boxed {P(7)=0.604938272}$$

Sanity Check:  Let's get $P(5)$ by hand.  The only "bad" sequences of length $5$ are $W^4B, BW^4, W^5$.  Easy to compute the probabilities of each and we get $$P(5)=1-2\times \left(\frac 23\right)^4\times \frac 13-\left( \frac 23 \right)^5=0.736625514$$ which matches the result obtained by the recursion.

Comment: On a brute force method, I am getting a value of P(7) = 0.487883, for a string of 7 and that there are not 4 or more consecutive whites appear?

Comment: @SatishRamanathan  You think you get four consecutive whites with probability greater than $\frac 12$?  What does your method give for $P(4),P(5),P(6)$?

Comment: @SatishRamanathan  Easy to check my result for $P(6)$.  The bad outcomes are $W^4*,BW^4*,BBW^4,WBW^4$.  Thus $P(6)=1-(\frac 23)^4-(\frac 13)*(\frac 23)^4-(\frac 13)^2\times (\frac 23)^4-(\frac 23)*(\frac 13)*(\frac 23)^4=0.670781893$ which matches the result of my recursion, so I am standing by it.

Answer (score 0):

@lulu

But here is my account for a string of 6 and 7 string with not 4 or more consecutive whites(I find the 4 or more consecutive and subtract it from 1)

It absolutely confirms your calculation. Lulu can't be wrong

[image]

Comment: Well, as you are aware, it is hard to debug brute force methods. Very error prone. That's why I gave multiple methods to get at lower cases here. I'm not sure what your chart means, but if the numbers in the third column, $4,12,3,5,2,1$, are meant to be "number of arrangements of the given type" then it is wrong.  The $5$ for example is way off...The only two arrangements that work are $W^5BW, WBW^5$.    Also the $12$ is wrong.  Some of the others look right, and of course I may be misinterpreting the chart.

Comment: I highly recommend looking at my recursion.  Of course, it may be wrong.  Algebraic mistakes are very easy to make with this kind of stuff.  But it isn't conceptually wrong and it certainly gives the right answer for small strings.  If correct, it effortlessly gives the answer for very large strings as well.  If incorrect, the mistake ought to be easy to track down and repair.

Comment: @lulu, You are right, 5 is wrong and I will check the results later. I believe your calculation and hopefully I have made some mistake.  Sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: Oh, don't apologize.  These computations are horribly error prone.  I believe my recursion, but I could easily have botched the math or the implementation.  Any way, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @lulu.  You were absolutely right on your recursive relationship and the brute force method just validated it.

Comment: Phew!  As I expect you have noticed, the sort of bugs that creep into this kind of computation can be hard to track.  Thanks for taking the trouble to check!